# Can I create dynamically stages in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to launch a dynamic set of tests in a declarative pipeline.
For better visualization purposes, I'd like to create a stage for each test.
Is there a way to do so?

The only way to create a stage I know is:

```
stage('foo') {
   ...
}
```

I've seen [this example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/jenkinsfile-examples/android-build-flavor-from-branch/JenkinsFile), but I it does not use declarative syntax.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the scripted syntax that allows more flexibility than the declarative syntax, even though the declarative is more documented and recommended.

For example stages can be created in a loop:

```
def tests = params.Tests.split(',')
for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
    stage("Test ${tests[i]}") {
        sh '....'
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to put the loop inside a `script` block of the first `stage` that I call `Initialize`.

Comment: @haridsv and for the display pipeline, does it show you seperately the stages ?

Comment: @codeGeass Yes, and it seems to also account the time correctly (i.e., it doesn't aggregate the time to the `Initialize` stage).

Comment: You can visualize with Blue Ocean ? because I just get the Initialize stage and other stages are like steps of that stage.

Comment: This seems not to be working. Can you provide a complete example ? From what I unterstood we need to create a Pipeline project then that snippet does not work...

Comment: This does not work. First off, there must be steps. And I can't get dynamically created stages in the steps block

Comment: The code had a typo ( fixed it). This works for me, it creates stages depending on the input parameter.
You need an input parameter named 'Tests' which is a coma (',') separated list of test cases.
Conceptual issues: If you change the input, it creates new stages and you loose the history.

Comment: @haridsv it seems to work BUT there is one big draw on this: the restart stage feature does only detect your INIT stage as restartable stage. The "substages" are not restartable

Comment: @Dakkar Thanks for pointing that out! I have never tried that feature so was unaware of this limitation.

Comment: All this works and I was also able to run dynamically generated stages in parallel. I see 2 issues btw, one is that Blu Ocean doesn't interpret really well the sequential stages ran in parallel (so I guess same as @codeGeass) the other problem is that in the workflow view the execution time sometimes reports NaNy NaNd. I believe that what interprets the pipeline might get confused view complex structures

Answer (score 38):

If you don't want to use `for` loop, and generated pipeline to be executed in parallel then, here is an answer.

```
def jobs = ["JobA", "JobB", "JobC"]
 
def parallelStagesMap = jobs.collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}
 
def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("stage: ${job}") {
                echo "This is ${job}."
        }
    }
}
 
pipeline {
    agent none
 
    stages {
        stage('non-parallel stage') {
            steps {
                echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
            }
        }
 
        stage('parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Note` that all generated stages will be executed into 1 node.
If you are willing to executed the generated stages to be executed into different nodes.

```
def agents  = ['master', 'agent1', 'agent2']
// enter valid agent name in array.

def generateStage(nodeLabel) {
    return {
        stage("Runs on ${nodeLabel}") { 
            node(nodeLabel) {
                echo "Running on ${nodeLabel}"
            }
        }
    }
}
def parallelStagesMap = agents.collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('non-parallel stage') {
            steps {
                echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
            }
        }

        stage('parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

You can of course add more than 1 parameters and can use `collectEntries` for 2 parameters.

Please remember `return` in function `generateStage` is must.

Comment: Concise, and it works with Jenkins 2.263.4

Comment: Hi, thank u! It works for me. But now, I want to cleanWorkspace on each agent. Where can I add this script: ```post { cleanup { cleanWs() }}}```  Please help!
Thank in advance!

Comment: What do you do if you need to include `agent`/`environment`/`steps`/`post` in the generated stages?

Answer (score 36):

As JamesD suggested, you may create stages dynamically (but they will be sequential) like that:

```
def list
pipeline {
    agent none
    options {buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '7', numToKeepStr: '1'))}
    stages {
        stage('Create List') {
            agent {node 'nodename'}
            steps {
                script {
                    // you may create your list here, lets say reading from a file after checkout
                    list = ["Test-1", "Test-2", "Test-3", "Test-4", "Test-5"]
                }
            }
            post {
                cleanup {
                    cleanWs()
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Dynamic Stages') {
            agent {node 'nodename'}
            steps {
                script {
                    for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        stage(list[i]){
                            echo "Element: $i"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            post {
                cleanup {
                    cleanWs()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That will result in:
[dynamic-sequential-stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxfeB.png)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, man! As an alternative to `for (...) {`, I was able to use `list.each { listItem ->`. I assume that `list.eachWithIndex { listItem, i ->` would also work, for people who happen to need the index.

Comment: can we use multiple stages in a for loop?

Answer (score 25):

@Jorge Machado: Because I cannot comment I had to post it as an answer. I've solved it recently. I hope it'll help you.

Declarative pipeline:

A simple static example:

```
stage('Dynamic') {
        steps {
            script {
                stage('NewOne') {

                        echo('new one echo')

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Dynamic real-life example:

```
    // in a declarative pipeline
        stage('Trigger Building') {
              when {
                environment(name: 'DO_BUILD_PACKAGES', value: 'true')
              }
              steps {
                executeModuleScripts('build') // local method, see at the end of this script
              }
            }


    // at the end of the file or in a shared library
        void executeModuleScripts(String operation) {

          def allModules = ['module1', 'module2', 'module3', 'module4', 'module11']

          allModules.each { module ->  
          String action = "${operation}:${module}"  

          echo("---- ${action.toUpperCase()} ----")        
          String command = "npm run ${action} -ddd"                   

            // here is the trick           
            script {
              stage(module) {
                bat(command)
              }
            }
          }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I didn't pay as much attention to your response as I should have, because the lack of a `steps` block within the inner stage definition is quite important. Hopefully this may help someone else who just skimmed instead of really reading :)

Answer (score 21):

You might want to take a look at [this example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/parallel-from-list/parallelFromList.groovy) - you can have a function return a closure which *should* be able to have a stage in it.

This code shows the concept, but doesn't have a stage in it.

```
def transformDeployBuildStep(OS) {
    return {
        node ('master') { 
        wrap([$class: 'TimestamperBuildWrapper']) {
...
        } } // ts / node
    } // closure
} // transformDeployBuildStep

stage("Yum Deploy") {
  stepsForParallel = [:]
  for (int i = 0; i < TargetOSs.size(); i++) {
      def s = TargetOSs.get(i)
      def stepName = "CentOS ${s} Deployment"
      stepsForParallel[stepName] = transformDeployBuildStep(s)
  }
  stepsForParallel['failFast'] = false
  parallel stepsForParallel
} // stage
```

Comment: @Aaron, after i create the array, how can i run it not in parallel ?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it not in parallel. Why would you? Just execute what you need to when you need to?

Comment: Somebody just upvoted this almost three years later and brought me back - my example code above has now been open sourced - https://github.com/opencpi/opencpi/blob/develop/releng/jenkins/runtime/groovy/Jenkinsfile_Job1.groovy

Comment: You can use .call() on the returned instance, for nonparallel building.

Answer (score 9):

Just an addition to what [@np2807](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5360233/np2807) and [@Anton Yurchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10483800/anton-yurchenko) have already presented: you can create stages dynamically and run the in parallel by simply delaying list of stages creation (but keeping its declaration), e.g. like that:

```
def parallelStagesMap

def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("stage: ${job}") {
                echo "This is ${job}."
        }
    }
}
 
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
 
    stages {
        stage('Create List of Stages to run in Parallel') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def list = ["Test-1", "Test-2", "Test-3", "Test-4", "Test-5"]
                    // you may create your list here, lets say reading from a file after checkout
                    // personally, I like to use scriptler scripts and load the as simple as:
                    // list = load '/var/lib/jenkins/scriptler/scripts/load-list-script.groovy'
                    parallelStagesMap = list.collectEntries {
                        ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 
        stage('Run Stages in Parallel') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That will result in Dynamic Parallel Stages:
[image: Dynamic Parallel Stages pipeline diagram]

Comment: You can do it all in a single stage: `parallel list.collectEntries { [ (it): { stage(it) { echo "This is ${it}" } } ] }`

Comment: @OrangeDog you're right and I love it! Sometimes I forget how flexible Groovy is

Answer (score 3):

I use this to generate my stages which contain a Jenkins job in them.
build_list is a list of Jenkins jobs that i want to trigger from my main Jenkins job, but have a stage for each job that is trigger.

```
build_list = ['job1', 'job2', 'job3']
        for(int i=0; i < build_list.size(); i++) {
          stage(build_list[i]){
               build job: build_list[i], propagate: false
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Jenkinsfile then, I achieved it via dynamically creating the stages, running them in parallel and also getting Jenkinsfile UI to show separate columns. This assumes parallel  steps are independent of each other (otherwise don't use parallel) and you can nest them as deep as you want (depending upon the # of for loops you'll nest for creating stages).

[Jenkinsfile Pipeline DSL: How to Show Multi-Columns in Jobs dashboard GUI - For all Dynamically created stages - When within PIPELINE section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885845/jenkinsfile-pipeline-dsl-how-to-show-multi-columns-in-jobs-dashboard-gui-for) see here for more.