# For the Jenkins Pipeline plugin, how do I get named parallel steps to display

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

For the following sample, the display of the job lumps all "Tests" together. Is there a way to show each individual test stacked horizontally?  See attached picture.

```
node ('master') {
  stage("Setup") {
    echo "setting up tests on master"
  }
  stage("Tests") {
    def stepsToRun = [:]
    for (String name : resultList) {
      stepsToRun["Tests:${name}"] = { node('another_build_node') {
          echo "start |${name}|"
          sleep 1
          echo "done'"
        }}
      }
      println stepsToRun
      parallel stepsToRun
  }
  stage("Teardown") {
    echo "post-test teardown on master"
  }
}
```

[image: job display]

Comment: resultList contents is unimportant, only that it is a list of tests to run in my real code

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to see parallel steps in this UI. 
Use Jenkins BlueOcean plugin: https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/

Answer (score 0):

No. A [Pipeline "stage"](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/):

> is a step for defining a conceptually distinct subset of the entire
>   Pipeline, for example: "Build", "Test", and "Deploy", which is *used by
>   many plugins to visualize or present* Jenkins Pipeline status/progress.

The workflow decomposes by Stage because they are the driving components in the following workflow:

[image: Jenkins Pipeline Stages]

**However**, you could try to create dynamic stages, as several answers here suggest: [Can I create dynamically stages in a Jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837066/can-i-create-dynamically-stages-in-a-jenkins-pipeline)