# jenkins groovy with loop

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to add similar stages to Jenkins pipeline, something like:

```
pipeline {
       stage('Publish archives to Artifactory - common') {
        steps {
            dir('android/build/artifacts_output/common') {
                script {
                    def server = Artifactory.server 'artifactory'
                        def uploadSpec = """{
                            "files": [
                            {
                                "pattern": "*.*",
                                "target": "my-repo/1.0.0/common"
                            }
                            ]
                        }"""

                    server.upload(uploadSpec)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stage('Publish archives to Artifactory - core') {
        steps {
            dir('android/core') {
                script {
                    def server = Artifactory.server 'artifactory'
                        def uploadSpec = """{
                            "files": [
                            {
                                "pattern": "*.*",
                                "target": "my-repo/1.0.0/core"
                            }
                            ]
                        }"""

                    server.upload(uploadSpec)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add some more stages like this, for different modules.
Is there a better way to do it, like adding stages with loop, instead of copy-pasting this code many times?

This snippet is written in Groovy. I'm not familiar enough with the syntax of Groovy...

**EDIT**

Also found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837066/can-i-create-dynamically-stages-in-a-jenkins-pipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach would be to provide a list of configuration objects and then iterate over the list

```
def list = ["Conf 1", "Conf 2", "Conf 3", "Conf Last"]

list.each { stageName ->
    node {
        stage(stageName) {
            println(stageName)
        }
    }
}
```

In your case you would rather need maps or some other kind of parameter objects in the list.

Comment: Thank! So all I need is to put the stages in 'node', and they will be added to the pipeline?