# How to create methods for steps in Jenkins Declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to wrap `steps` and `post` in a function.

This works fine:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                whateverFunction()
            }
            post {
                sh 'echo test'
            }
        }
    }
}

void whateverFunction() {
    sh 'ls /'
}
```

But as soon as I pack steps and post in my function it does not work. (Fail's with the error: `steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block.`)

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            whateverFunction()
        }
    }
}

void whateverFunction() {
    steps {
        sh 'echo test'  
    }
    post {
        sh 'echo test'
    }
}
```

What I also tried is to have `steps` and then call my function in that step with a `steps` inside. Basically warping `steps` in `steps` which leads to the behavior that no step is executed. (But apparently it would be a valid Jenkins-file)

Is it possible to have a function which contains `steps` and `post` inside a stage. Or is there a way to achieve a similar functionality?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837066/can-i-create-dynamically-stages-in-a-jenkins-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that you cannot create similar functionality with `post` inside a method in declarative pipeline. To achieve this you can try to use scripted pipelines.

For declarative pipelines you can use `post` section only inside `stage` ([example](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post)) or after `stages` block ([example](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/)).