# Jenkins Pipeline Make a Stage as a Variable?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
stages {
    stage('Setup') {
    }
    stage('Parallel Stage') {
        parallel {
            stage('Executor 1') {
            }
            stage('Executor 2') {
            } 
            stage('Executor 3') {
            } 
            stage('Executor 4') {
            }                                          
        }
    }
}
```

Above is a skeleton of my Jenkins pipeline that has a setup stage and then a parallel stage that does the same thing four times for faster execution time.

Is there a way to define a stage as a variable to reduce the 4x code repetition and to reduce the number of edits I would have to make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, best way is to defined a function which generates stage and can be called in parallel.

Presuming that you are executing the stages into 1 agent in parallel.

In below sample pipeline `generateStage` is a function which replaces nested stages with function.

```
def jobs = ["Executor1", "Executor2", "Executor3"]
 
def parallelStagesMap = jobs.collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}
 
def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("${job}") {
                echo "Running stage ${job}."
        }
    }
}
 
pipeline {
    agent any
 
    stages {
        stage('setup') {
            steps {
                echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
            }
        }
 
        stage('parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output of the pipeline is as below:

[image]

For more details please see my answer [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837066/can-i-create-dynamically-stages-in-a-jenkins-pipeline/66438907#66438907)

Only drawback is that you can not execute this pipeline arrangement directly after `stages` thats why `parallelStageMap` is called inside the script.

Comment: When place the three variables after, Jenkins complains about paralleStagesMap not being defined. When placing the three variables above pipeline as seen in your example, I get `WorkflowScript: 64: Expected a stage @ line 64, column 13.
               stage('Setup') {
               ^

WorkflowScript: 84: Expected a stage @ line 84, column 13.
               stage('Parallel Stage') {
               ^

WorkflowScript: 63: No stages specified @ line 63, column 9.
           stages

Comment: @atg I have updated my snippet and output of pipeline.

Comment: thank you! i'll try running it and I'll let you know how it goes. I feel like this is really close. it's probably an issue with the actual commands I'm trying to run but I'll see.

Comment: Thank you @np2807 I managed to get it working. starting over and gradually adding steps helped.