# jenkins groovy generate stages based on lines from file.txt

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

Having this working scripts :

`file.txt` contains :

```
line0=[acme01, acme02, acme03, acme04]
line1=[acme11, acme12, acme13, acme14]
line2=[acme21, acme22, acme23, acme24]
line3=[acme31, acme32, acme33, acme34]
```

and this below line is declared globally (located before "pipeline {}"

```
def (image_properties, branch) = [ [image_tags:[]], null ]
```

This below is working (prints expected result as per array value for line0,line1,line2,line3. Rather than manually adding stages because in future, new lines will be added to `file.txt` , how do we dynamically generate the stages ? So that in each stage, we can add scripting to perform split and run parallel stages..

```
        stage('Read and assign lines') {
            steps{
                script {
                def build_properties = readProperties file: "file.txt"
                image_properties.putAll(build_properties)

                }
            }
        }

        stage('validating  - line0') {
            steps{
                script {
                     container("${opts.container}") {
                         println("line Content: ${image_properties.line0}")
                     }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('validating  - line1') {
            steps{
                script {
                     container("${opts.container}") {
                         println("line Content: ${image_properties.line1}")
                     }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('validating  - line2') {
            steps{
                script {
                     container("${opts.container}") {
                         println("line Content: ${image_properties.line2}")
                     }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('validating  - line3') {
            steps{
                script {
                     container("${opts.container}") {
                         println("line Content: ${image_properties.line3}")
                     }
                }
            }
        }
```

We agree we can achieve by doing like this, this below works however, wants stage wise only

```
         stage('validating') {
            failFast false
            steps{
                script {
                    def jobs=[]
                    def filePath = readFile('file.txt').trim()
                    def lines = filePath.readLines()
                    lines.each { job -> 
                    jobs.add("${job}")
                    }
                    def parallelStagesMap = jobs.collectEntries{
                          ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
                    }
                    parallel parallelStagesMap                    
                }
            }
         }
```

and

```
def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("stage: ${job}") {
            script{
                echo "This is ${job}."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

expecting this way only
[refer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WkpS.png)

Expecting new stages to be generated automatically as per file.txt

Answer (score 0):

never mind this instruction helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42838326/23316757

However, still lacks ability to restart specific stage (incase of failure). Suspecting known limitation with jenkins logics...